# Get Windows 10 safe mode with only bios

Tags: windows-10, bios, safe-mode

I have a PC under windows 10 and I have the black screen with mouse issue, probable due to some graphic driver.

Anyway, I already had this problem some days ago, and to solve it I had reboot my Windows on safe mode, and return it to a restauration point from this safe mode.

Now that I have the same issue I wanted to do the same trick but it seems that I can't do the shift+restart way to boot on safe mode from the login screen because I don't have the login button anymore.

I've seen that it is an option that can be turned off, and my last restart seems to have done it.

Finally, I want to boot in safe mode or reinitialise my Windows but I can only acces the bios and the login screen.

Do someone have any idea how I can do this without booting on a CD or key ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks,
Yvonnig

Comment: Is the PC completing the POST?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure to understand what the post is but I think so, since I manage to go to the login screen ...

Comment: I am confused. You first say you have a black screen then say you have the login screen. Well if you get to the login screen then all you need to do is hold SHIFT whilst clicking the power button and keep SHIFT pressed when clicking restart. If your computer completes POST (Power On Self Test - checking RAM etc.) and you can't get to the login screen the only way is by using a windows disk or USB key

Comment: POST is a test; it happens before you are prompted to access the firmware, of any pc

Comment: Okey, I might have explain it badly : I can go to the login screen, but if I login I got a black screen. And I can't do the shift + restart because I don't have the login button anymore on the login page ...

Comment: I've search for it and apparently this login button can be activated or desactivated when you've acces to your files but actually I don't ...